# ImageButton text

Tags: asp.net

Hi there i am trying to do "simple" thing and cant manage to work it out

.net,
in my site i have a nav menu each item in the menu is an image

(like here in the upper "menu" Questions..Tags..etc.. but the background color in my case is an image)

i want to load an image and dynamically add text to it from the server side
i cant manage to add text to it .
what is the best approach 
i want to be able to do something like the follow:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton" runat="Server" ImageUrl="nav1.gif" **text=""**/>
```

and from the server just to be able to write on it something like the follow:

**imgButton.text="AA"**

appreciate any help:)
Thank Eran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css and an unordered list (`<ul>`) to achieve such an effect. just style the list items (`<li>`) to have a background image and place `asp:labels` (which can be access from your code behind to change dynamically) within the listitems

Answer (score 0):

Your image button's text property controls the value of the element's [AlternateText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.alternatetext) property and according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.text) is not intended to be called directly from your code.  What you may want to do instead is to use a `LinkButton`, and set the background of the button to your image using css perhaps.  This will enable you to have both image and text.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a normal asp button but set an image using the style/css.

Set the style/css of the button to `background-color: transparent;` and then to change the image, set the image using the background property `background: url([dir]/nav1.gif);`

The text property will work as you are expecting with the imagebutton. The button text style can be modified as normal css ie. colour and font-size etc.